# its rather basic I need help to understand c and my programm keeps relling me there's an error. it keeps saying error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token

Tags: c

Here is the code that i need help with

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()

    {
      int x = 10, y = 20, z;
      for (z = 0, z < y; z++)
        {
          if (z == x)
        {
            printf ("%d\n", z);
            }
            else
            {
         break;
           }
        }
```

Comment: Now that I've indented your code- do you see the problem?

Comment: Also most likely, `for (z = 0, z < y; z++)` --> `for (z = 0; z < y; z++)`

Comment: fix the indentations, it will be more clear to you where you are missing the closing bracket `}`.

Comment: Your coding style is all over the place. Adopt a sane coding style if you expect others to help you chasing down syntax bugs.

Comment: will do, Im a beginner though

Answer (score 1):

In for loop you can't use ',' to separate declarations.

It should be `for( z=0; z<y; z++)`

and also if you use `break;` it will terminate in 1st iteration.
So correct program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()

{
    int x = 10, y = 20, z;
    for (z = 0; z < y; z++)
    {
        if (z == x)
        {
            printf ("%d\n", z);
        }
        else
        {
             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues as I can see:

1. You have missing curly braces, to properly enclose the scopes.
2. The syntax of the `for` loop is not correct. Simply

   ```
   for (z = 0, z < y; z++)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   for (z = 0; z < y; z++)
           ^^-----------------------the , is to be ;
   ```

That said, for a hosted environment, the usual signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`, in case you want to ignore the command line arguments.